# Calculate sum of amount in a month before a certain date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Initial df

```
d = {'salesman': ['Andy', 'Brown','Charlie'], 
     'training_date': ['2020-04-16','2021-03-04','2021-03-08'],
     'sales_in_training_month':['0','2634','2856.5']
    }
df_initial = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_initial
```

Expected df

```
d2 = {'salesman': ['Andy', 'Brown','Charlie'], 
     'training_date': ['2020-04-16','2021-03-04','2021-03-08'],
     'sales_in_training_month':[0,2634,2856.5],
     'sales_per_day_in_training_month':[0,87.8,92.14],
     'sales_in_training_month_before_training_date':[0,263.4,644.98]
    }
df_post = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df_post
```

Explanation:
I want to calculate the sum of the sales of each salesman in the month, before his/her training date. 
Andy, 0 sales, so 0.
Brown was trained on March 4th. In March, his sales was $2634. There are 31 days in March, so his sales per day during his training month was approximately $87.8. $87.8 multiplied by the number of days before his training day (3) results in $263.4.
I am open to receiving a more efficient approach to achieve the same goal: getting the sales amount in the training month, before the training date.

Apart from the initial df, the table I received from the data warehouse is in the format of:

```
d_0 = {'salesman': ['Andy', 'Brown','Charlie'],
     'sales':['0','2634','2856.5'],
     'transaction_month':['2020-04-01','2020-05-01','2020-06-01']
    }
df_0 = pd.DataFrame(data=d_0)
df_0
```

Note:
I am using an approximation method as the dataset is huge, so querying daily sales will take a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Convert the dates to `datetime`.
- `groupby` "salesman", then by month.
- The "day" field of the training date gives you the number of days before training (after subtracting 1).
- Divide this by days in the month (a function call on the month
  number) to get the proportion of sales before training.
- Multiple that proportion by the total sales; that gives you the interpolated sales before training.

Follow the business logic for why this is a useful figure, but these steps should give you the result you describe.  Note that the arithmetic in you example is incorrect; $2634 / 31 gives $84.97; you divided by 30, not 31.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate more on "a function call on the month number?" I am having difficulties trying to get the number of days of the month of a date.

Comment: days in a given month is solved in many places on the net.  "Having difficulties" does not define your problem.

Comment: days in a given month is the key. many thanks!